# Explicar cómo funcionan doble guiones bajos "__"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Me podrían explicar cómo para que sirven los ***doble guiones bajos "`__`"*** y como es que funcionan exactamente, los he utilizado en ejemplos pero no entiendo el mecanismo correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los doble guiones bajos `(__)` se usan para las [búsquedas de campo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) , que se repiten en el diccionario creado utilizando argumentos de palabra clave de `Python`. Es similar a la cláusula `SQL WHERE`.

Se especifican como argumentos de palabras clave para los métodos [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/) que toman la forma general, pueden ser [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) , [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) o [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) `.field__lookuptype. lookuptypes`

Si bien la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) proporciona muchos más detalles, el quid la sintaxis es el `double-underscore`, que se utiliza para separar el nombre `field` de la función `lookuptype`, seguido del valor para comparar. Según la documentación, la sintaxis se escribe así:

```
field__lookuptype=value
```

Por lo tanto, si utiliza la sintaxis de búsqueda de campo/doble subrayado para buscar valores donde el campo `name` de su modelo contiene la palabra `Pedro`, usaría esta sintaxis:

```
name__contains='Pedro'
```

La parte crítica aquí es la sintaxis del nombre del campo primero, seguido por a `double-underscore` y luego el `lookuptype`. Las cosas pueden ser mucho más complejas que esto claro esta.

---

Ejemplo usando **filter()**:

Una nuestra de aplicación que tiene un modelo `Libro` con unos campos básicos: `titulo`, `autor`, y `fecha_publicacion`. Podemos ver rápidamente que la base de datos contiene 20 libros en total usando el método `count()`:

```
>>> Libro.objects.count()
20
```

Ahora, al usar `filter()`, podemos recuperar un `QuerySet` de aquellos libros que se publicaron en el período de los últimos 90 días, así:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> Libro.objects.filter(fecha_publicacion__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)).count()
3
```

Con `filter()`, podemos determinar que solo 3 de nuestros 20 libros en total se publicaron en el último período de 90 días.

> Puede obtener mas información aquí:
>
> - [How to Filter for Empty or Null Values in a Django QuerySet](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-filter-for-empty-or-null-values-in-a-django-queryset/)

Comment: Me podrían explicar con un ejemplo sencillo, y de ante mano disculpa las molestias

Comment: @PedroDiazLabiste revise la respuesta la he actualizado.

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name